# Sum large numpy array in chunks

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sum, h5py

I have a large 3D h5py dataset `frames` I want to sum along the first dimension. It does not fit all into memory so that I have to do:

```py
sh = frames.shape[0]

temp_1 = frames[:sh//2,...].sum(0)
temp_2 = frames[sh//2:,...].sum(0)

tot_img = temp_1 + temp_2
```

Is there a way to optimize this so that it computes faster?

Comment: What do you mean it does not fit all into memory? It seems that `frames` is already in memory. Are you saying that you can do `frames[:sh//2,...].sum(0) + frames[sh//2:,...].sum(0)` but not `frames.sum(0)`?

Comment: Sorry I was not clear - `frames` is a h5py dataset. Yes `frames.sum(0)` gives a memory error.